# How to change the font on ionic globally

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, google-font-api

I am using ionic version 3.9.2

What i want to achieve is i want to change all default font of the ionic app to my given custom font.

After googling a bit i got to understand that i have to set the font face thing in the `app.scss` which is present in the folder `app`

This was the code i used:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
$font-family-base: "Raleway", sans-serif !default;
```

However even after doing so i couldn't change the font of the whole app as it is not reflecting in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the Necessary fonts and links in the head part and just apply the styles to the following part of index.html file placed in src folder in an ionic 3 project

```
 <ion-app style="Whatever rules you want !font-family:family;"></ion-app>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do that.But I highly recommend not to use online URL as you have tried. Because your app will not show particular font when there will be no  wifi. So always install the font into your device and use it.

Here I'm showing how to install `Lato-Regular`. This process is same for any font.

*variables.scss*

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Lato-Regular";
        src: url($font-path+'/lato/Lato-Regular.ttf');
    }

   $font-family-base: "Lato-Regular";
```

*app.scss*

```
* {
    font-family: $font-family-base;
}
```

That is it. Here you can see a [**great video about it**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_oB5WvzBL0). If you'll have any issue please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

**It is so simple**
You just have to add these lines on *theme/variable.scss* and that's it

```
@import "roboto";
@import "noto-sans";
@import "../assets/fonts/quickSand.scss"; // this one I used for my app


$font-family-base: 'Quicksand';
$font-family-md-base: "Quicksand";
$font-family-ios-base: "Quicksand";
$font-family-wp-base: "Quicksand";
$font-size-base:  14px;
```